# How do I install OpenMPI, MPICH, and other MPI variants so that they work only locally, not globally?

Tags: linux, unix

What I want to do is install various versions of OpenMPI, MPICH, etc, so that I can run code specifically for those versions, but in a way that they don't mess up with each other.
I'm new to using Linux. Is there an easier way to do it than what I think should work (installing MPI's version in a folder so that it only works in that folder) or is there another way of doing it?

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 as my Linux distro.

Comment: This sounds more like a [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) board question

Comment: @SKPS I'll update the questions' tags accordingly

Answer (score 0):

For respective package, you need to see if they could be configurable during installation. Based on it, you can for example specify during the installation:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/local/directory
```

After this, you just need to "export" this path and might as well need to "include" the library path post installation.

```
export PATH=/path/to/local/directory/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/local/directory/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You can create different bash scripts which `export` and `include` the paths depending on the version you want to select.